# Use SqlGeography at ServiceStack.OrmLite in .Net Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I try to add SqlGeography to my model and when I call create table I got weird error.

First I add this package: `Microsoft.SqlServer.Types`

Then I create my model like example at below:

```
public class Locations 
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public SqlGeography Location { get; set; }
}
```

Then call `CreateTableIfNotExists` to create table

```
private void CheckDB(IDbConnectionFactory dbConnectionFactory)
{
    using (var db = dbConnectionFactory.Open())
    {
        db.CreateTableIfNotExists<Models.Entities.DbIpEntity>();
    }
}
```

And at end I got this error:

> System.TypeLoadException   HResult=0x80131522   Message=Could not load
>   type 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.IBinarySerialize' from assembly
>   'System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.   Source=System.Private.CoreLib
>   StackTrace:    at System.Signature.GetSignature(Void* pCorSig, Int32
>   cCorSig, RuntimeFieldHandleInternal fieldHandle, IRuntimeMethodInfo
>   methodHandle, RuntimeType declaringType)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.FetchNonReturnParameters()    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.GetParametersNoCopy()    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.GetIndexParametersNoCopy()    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.GetIndexParameters()    at
>   ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteConfigExtensions.GetModelDefinition(Type
>   modelType)    at
>   ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteWriteCommandExtensions.CreateTable(IDbCommand
>   dbCmd, Boolean overwrite, Type modelType)    at
>   ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteExecFilter.Exec[T](IDbConnection dbConn,
>   Func`2 filter)    at
>   ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteSchemaApi.DropAndCreateTable[T](IDbConnection
>   dbConn)    at GeoApi.AppHost.CheckDB(IDbConnectionFactory
>   dbConnectionFactory) in E:\Projects\Geo\AppHost.cs:line 48    at
>   GeoApi.AppHost.Configure(Container container) in
>   E:\Projects\Geo\AppHost.cs:line 40    at
>   ServiceStack.ServiceStackHost.Init()    at
>   ServiceStack.NetCoreAppHostExtensions.UseServiceStack(IApplicationBuilder
>   app, AppHostBase appHost)    at
>   GeoApi.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment
>   env) in E:\Projects\Geo\Startup.cs:line 49

In this error I realized it's looking for .Net Framework assembly ( `System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0` ) not .Net Core

Comment: pretty sure that the geo types use native code - as such, it probably won't play nicely on .net core... at all

Comment: @MarcGravell looks you right. i can see at service stack source it's iterating on properties of model and calling GetIndexParameters method and from there we get error https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.OrmLite/OrmLiteConfigExtensions.cs#L85

Comment: maybe @mythz have an idea

Comment: @MarcGravell Looks like that's no longer the case - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/spatial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlServer.Converters](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlServer.Converters) and [Microsoft.SqlServer.Types](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.Types/) where `SqlGeography` is defined is only available for .NET v4.5 and .NET v4.0 respectively so it requires a minimum of .NET v4.5 to run and can't be used in .NET Core.

Comment: Do you have any idea how can I use Geography in .Net core?

Comment: @OmidMafakher SqlGeography in SQL Server? I don't believe is supported in .NET Core. But if I need GEO features in .NET Core I'd use [Redis GEO support](https://github.com/NetCoreApps/redis-geo), there's also other options like [PostGIS](https://postgis.net) in which the team behind the [Npgsql](http://www.npgsql.org) ADO.NET provider is pretty responsive and active for adding support for .NET Core.

Comment: @mythz It looks like SqlGeography is now supported in dotnet core, is there a chance we might see this in OrmLite on dotnet core anytime soon? - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/spatial

Comment: @JMK like any enhancements/features please [submit a feature request](https://servicestack.uservoice.com/forums/176786-feature-requests) so we can record and measure interest.

Comment: @mythz I posted an answer below, I'd be happy to extend that into a PR?

Comment: @JMK would love that :)

Comment: @mythz Cool, it's a little late here but will get on that tomorrow evening!

Comment: @JMK Sounds good! FYI the [ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlServer/](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlServer/) contains both .NET v4.5 and .NET Standard 2.0 .dlls (for .NET Core), the packages ending with `*.Core` are only for [running ASP.NET Core on .NET Framework](http://docs.servicestack.net/templates-corefx).

Comment: @mythz Will keep that in mind and report back tomorrow, cheers :)

Answer (score 2):

.net core 2.2 now supports working with GeoSpatial data - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/spatial

I was able to knock together my own **OrmLiteConverter** based around [the **SqlServerGeographyTypeConverter** here.](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlServer.Converters/SqlServerGeographyTypeConverter.cs)

```
public class SqlServerIPointTypeConverter : OrmLiteConverter
{
    public override string ColumnDefinition => "geography";
    public override DbType DbType => DbType.Object;

    public override string ToQuotedString(Type fieldType, object value)
    {
        if (fieldType != typeof(IPoint)) return base.ToQuotedString(fieldType, value);

        string str = null;
        if (value != null)
        {
            var geo = (IPoint) value;
            str = geo.ToString();
        }

        str = (str == null) ? "null" : $"'{str}'";
        return $"CAST({str} AS {ColumnDefinition})";
    }

    public override void InitDbParam(IDbDataParameter p, Type fieldType)
    {
        if (fieldType == typeof(IPoint))
        {
            var sqlParam = (SqlParameter)p;
            sqlParam.IsNullable = fieldType.IsNullableType();
            sqlParam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Udt;
            sqlParam.UdtTypeName = ColumnDefinition;
        }

        base.InitDbParam(p, fieldType);
    }

    public override object FromDbValue(Type fieldType, object value)
    {
        switch (value)
        {
            case null:
            case DBNull _:
                return new Point(0, 0);
            case IPoint point:
                return point;
            case string _:
                return Parse(value.ToString());
            default:
                return base.FromDbValue(fieldType, value);
        }
    }

    public override object ToDbValue(Type fieldType, object value)
    {
        switch (value)
        {
            case null:
            case DBNull _:
                return new Point(0, 0);
            case IPoint _:
                return value;
            case string str:
                return Parse(str);
            default:
                return base.ToDbValue(fieldType, value);
        }
    }

    private static Point Parse(string rawPoint)
    {
        var split = rawPoint.Replace("POINT (", string.Empty)
            .Replace(")", string.Empty)
            .Trim()
            .Split(new[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        var longitude = Convert.ToDouble(split[0]);
        var latitude = Convert.ToDouble(split[1]);

        return new Point(longitude, latitude);
    }
}
```

Then in your *AppHost* file:

```
SqlServerDialect.Provider.RegisterConverter<Point>(new SqlServerIPointTypeConverter());
```

As long as you are on dotnet core 2.2, and have the following Nuget packages referenced, it should work:

- [Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.NetTopologySuite](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.NetTopologySuite/)
- [ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlServer.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlServer.Core/)

Comment: Which library defines IPoint in this example?